# MAAS PXE_BOOT: How can i limit what images are downloaded from the command 'import-boot-images'

Tags: juju, maas

I'm setting up a MAAS server where i want to download only one image for my nodes to boot via PXE_Boot.

when i initiate a command to import boot images i want to restrict to download only 14.04, how can i do that?

IS there a configuration file which i can edit?

Comment: user276565, did dimitern's response answer your question? If so, you can mark this as answered by clicking the green checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

In MAAS 1.5 and later (included in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty) the architecture has changed, so now the recommended way to import boot images is through the Web UI of MAAS at the "**Clusters**" page, clicking the "**Import boot images**" button. Alternatively, using the MAAS CLI commands, run:

`$ maas my-maas-session node-groups import-boot-images`

The configuration file that defines what images to download is in `/etc/maas/bootresources.yaml`. It looks like this:

`boot:
  sources:
  - keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg
    path: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/
    selections:
    - arches:
      - i386
      - amd64
      labels:
      - release
      - rc
      release: trusty
      subarches:
      - generic
    - arches:
      - i386
      - amd64
      labels:
      - release
      release: precise
      subarches:
      - generic
  storage: /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/`

To limit what gets downloaded, remove one or more entries from the list of arches, labels or subarches. For example, to only download images for series trusty-release-amd64-generic, leave only this in the file:

`boot:
  sources:
  - keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg
    path: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/
    selections:
    - arches:
      - amd64
      labels:
      - release
      release: trusty
      subarches:
      - generic
  storage: /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/`

Hope this helps! [MAAS documentation](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html#import-the-boot-images) about that needs to be updated to include this, so thanks for reporting it - I've filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1315463) for it.

Comment: Should "maas my-maas-session node-groups import-boot-images" be typed verbatim? My system doesn't seem to have a man page associated with maas; I'm not sure if this is proper.

Comment: No, sorry if it wasn't obvious. Replace `my-maas-session` with the name you picked for your MAAS CLI connection you chose when you ran `maas login` initially. Run `maas login -h` to see the documentation.